# How do i add an empty option to state value in magento2 checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, state

I'm working on customizing the Magento 2 checkout page, and I need to add an empty option to the state field in the billing address section. I want this empty option to be displayed as the first option in the dropdown list, allowing customers to select it if they don't have a state or if it's not applicable in their country.

I have already located the template file responsible for rendering the state field

**Magento_Checkout > web > template > billing**.

Look for the file named **address-renderer/default.html.**
, but I'm unsure about the exact modifications needed to achieve this. Could someone provide guidance on how to add an empty option to the state field in Magento 2 checkout?

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!